# Metaplex Account and Update Metadata

Tags: metaplex, token, metadata, metaboss

Im surching and trying now about 3 days, but I never find a simple answer:

Where do I find, a step by step doc, to install the metaplex-foundation "file". I´ve already done the "npm install @metaplex-foundation/js @solana/web3.js" then tried with:

import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);

and getting this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Can someone provide with a really simple doc to install and create then the metaplex account V 2 or 3?

I´ve already created a token wiht metaboss, but could not update my metadata. So I tried to do a new one with a pic (I forgot the pic at the first time). I generate the token with metaboss, but already do not see the pic, just "Token Logo" but not my pic. May someone also help me here? I put the uri in the metadata (uploadet up on pinata).

I searched for all this stuff, but as newbie, its not that easy :D

Thank you

Comment: For your first error: This indicates a syntax error in your code, so it would be helpful if you could post the full code you're using. The second part is unrelated, so I suggest you open a separate question for that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running your javascript file as a bash script. You will need to install and use Node. Name your file `index.mjs`, then run it with `node ./index.mjs`

You will need to bring in the private key for the update authority and do something like this:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
const mint = "The mint address of the NFT you want to update";
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([The funded update authority key here in an array of decimal numbers]))
(async () => {
    metaplex.use(keypair);
    const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress: new PublicKey(mint)});
    const sig = await metaplex.nfts().update({
        nftOrSft: nft,
        uri: "http://example.com/new-metadata.json",
    })
    console.log(sig);
})()
```